# Querying One Dimensional JSON string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, json-value

I'm trying to check to see if a one dimensional array string like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

contains a certain value, like 4.

I know with multi-dimensional arrays I could do something like:

```
JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$.key')
```

but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to search a keyless json string.

I've tried:

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$') = 1
WHERE JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$.') = 1
WHERE 1 IN JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$')
WHERE 1 IN JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$.')
```

and nothing works.

Comment: SQL 2016 - the version of SQL I have.

Comment: Yes - my version of MS SQL SERVER is 2016... i feel like we're focusing very heavily on something that is not worth focusing on lol.

Comment: When it comes to JSON, the specific dbms is important!

Comment: It's a string, can you use `like` or `charindex`?

Comment: and do what like ... (columnName LIKE ',1,' OR columnName LIKE '[1,' OR columnName LIKE ',1]') .... seems like a JSON function would be muuuuch easier

Comment: Well as per the usual it depends caveat, it depends. If the requirement is to simply ascertain if a value exists, as the description suggests, then why overcomplicate it.

Comment: I feel like doing multiple LIKE this or that or this other thing for each possible variation is overcomplicating it.... it would be great if i could do something like JSON_VALUE(columnName, '$') = 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string `'[1,2,3,4,5]'` is in a column in your table, you could use an `EXISTS` with `OPENJSON`:

```sql
SELECT V.YourColumn
FROM (VALUES('[1,2,3,4,5]'),('[7,8,9]'))V(YourColumn)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OPENJSON(V.YourColumn) 
                   WITH (Value int '$') OJ
              WHERE Value = 4);
```

Comment: OPENJSON isn't a function in my version of ms sql.

Comment: Dumb question, but why is the `WITH` line required? This seems to return the same with or without it in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Brds actually `openjson` is in Sql2016 - using `exists` would actually work fine

Comment: `openjson` requires compatibility set to 130 or higher, so it's reasonable that OP can't see it (a DBA could change this with `ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130`).

Comment: It's not "required" @EdmCoff , but I'd rather the `OPENJSON` return an `int` than an `nvarchar(MAX)` which then needs to be implicitly converted to an `int`.

Comment: `OPENJSON` isn't a function, @Brds , it's an operator, and it is available in SQL Server 2016, as Stu mentioned; in fact it was introduced with that version.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for clarifying about the `WITH`. As I mentioned previously, many default installs of SQL Server 2016 do not have `OPENJSON` available (so it will throw a "OPENJSON is not a recognized built-in function name" error) unless the compatibility is explicitly set.

Comment: *"As I mentioned previously, many default installs of SQL Server 2016 do not have OPENJSON available"* By default the compatibility level of a SQL Server 2016 instance is 130 @EdmCoff , so the complete opposite of this statement is true. By Default they *will* have it. It is only if someone lowers the compatibility that it won't be.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying. I guess I was wrong about the default compatibility. I think I over-interpreted the line "Compatibility level 120 may be the default even in a new Azure SQL Database" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and assumed it also applied outside Azure.

Comment: Yep, Azure SQL Databases have a default of 140 now, @EdmCoff, and have for some time. I've raised an [Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6278) for the document.